# Type conversion struts2?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jakarta-ee, struts2

I have my **struts.xml**:

```
<s:textfield id="thresholdParameter_1"
    name="gmathreshold.distinctBnumberRatio">
</s:textfield></td>
```

where gmathreshold is a bean with `distinctBnumberRatio` as member variable. In my bean it's a `BigDecimal`. So how can I get it set in my Bean. I mean how to convert from `String` to `BigDecimal` in **struts2**??

Comment: what you are asking is provided by Struts2 OOB, in case you need to define custom type convertor, you need to write it and configure it in S2.have a look at http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/type-conversion.html

Answer (score 1):

> how to convert from String to `BigDecimal`

The [BigDecimal(java.lang.String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal%28java.lang.String%29) constructor takes `String` argument.

> Translates the string representation of a `BigDecimal` into a `BigDecimal`. The string representation consists of an optional sign, '+' ( '\u002B') or '-' ('\u002D'), followed by a sequence of zero or more decimal digits ("the integer"), optionally followed by a fraction, optionally followed by an exponent.

For example,

```
String distinctBnumberRatioStr = "124.20";
BigDecimal distinctBnumberRatio = new BigDecimal(str);
```

### Update

Answer to you [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20896322/type-conversion-struts2/20896819?noredirect=1#comment31364970_20896819)

> String in JSP to BigDecimal in ActionClass

[From docs TypeConversion-BuiltinTypeConversionSupport](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.0.x/docs/type-conversion.html#TypeConversion-BuiltinTypeConversionSupport)

Type Conversion is implemented by XWork.

XWork will automatically handle the most common type conversion for you. This includes support for converting to and from Strings for each of the following:

- String
- boolean / Boolean
- char / Character
- int / Integer, float / Float, long / Long, double / Double
- dates - uses the SHORT format for the Locale associated with the current request
- arrays - assuming the individual strings can be coverted to the individual items
- collections - if not object type can be determined, it is assumed to be a String and a new ArrayList is created
- Enumerations
- BigDecimal and BigInteger

Note that with arrays the type conversion will defer to the type of the array elements and try to convert each item individually. As with any other type conversion, if the conversion can't be performed the standard type conversion error reporting is used to indicate a problem occured while processing the type conversion.

Comment: I wanted to know about that how in struts2 this type conversion is done.

Comment: @SiddharthTrikha : In struts2 mens what? In action class or on JSP? I am not getting?

Comment: String in JSP to BigDecimal in ActionClass